# How do I create a dynamic json array?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have the following javascript code:

```
var eventItems = {
        "addevent": { name: "Add New Event" },
        "addtodo": { name: "Add New Todo" }
    };
console.log(eventItems);
```

How can I create the eventItems object dynamically?  I've tried this, and it doesn't work.

```
var eventItems = [];
eventItems.push({ "addevent": { name: "Add New Event" } });
eventItems.push({ "addtodo": { name: "Add New Todo" } });
console.log(eventItems);
```

I realize the first statement isn't an array, but I'm not sure of the syntax to add these 2 elements dynamically one at a time.
Edited: modified question to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You say you want to make an **array**, so the second piece of code is correct. The first piece of code involves an object that's not an array.

Comment: try `console.log(eventItems.toString());` It will output your array in text format on the console you will than probably be able to read the value of each items. Or you could do `console.log(JSON.stringify(eventItems));` this should help you debug what is going on or at least give you a clue. because the output of your console that you post here is perfectly normal. -EDIT- the console output was remove from the post.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: Still doesn't make much sense to me... What is the problem? this code should work, no???

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too, but it doesn't.  The first is not an array, but I don't know how to dynamically add elements without making it an array.

Comment: Here is a jsBin of your code, it indeed works http://jsbin.com/devote/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I think I know! try removing the double quotes exemple : `{ addevent: { name: "Add New Event" } }`

Comment: @Scottie: What do you want your output to look like?  Can you show us what you are trying to create in the end?  Do you just simply want to do this? `var eventItems = {};  eventItems['addevent'] = { name: "Add New Event" };`?

Comment: On the first example, my console.log is showing "Object {addevent: Object, addtodo: Object}"  The second is showing: [Object, Object].  I want the second to look exactly like the first.  Removing the quotes didn't work.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat YES!!  That's exactly what I was after!!  That worked perfectly!  Copy as an answer and I'll accept.  Thank you!